# How toset the highlighted input field focused, in Intro.js?

Tags: intro.js

1) I'm using **intro.js** plugin for my website.

Everything is working fine. But I need to set the focus to highlighted element.mean to say user don't have to use the mouse to click on the input field to enter the data.

2) Is there a way to check any `introJs()` is running or not?